# What are the possible issues in installing Symfony on shared hosting

Tags: php, symfony1, hosting

I have developed an application in symfony which will have to be made live in few days. On a shared hosting service provider like GoDaddy I will have to keep the whole framework in the public_html.

Certainly there are security issues but cant they be fixed in some way or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that Symfony is simply excellent when it comes to dedicated hosting. For very security conscious person it is a simply No-No situation but in that case even shared hosting should be No-No for such applications.

The most annoying thing about symfony was that everything was under public_html. so the user could very easily read by yaml files. I could fix this using hotlink protection. Now thats certainly not fullproof but for my application it is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read [this page](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/SharedHostingNotSecure)? I think it covers the most severe security issues with symfony and shared hosting. I found it by searching 'symfony shared hosting' on google.

Comment: I have a hard time believing that most professional web hosts actually give every user full access to all others' files. With most commercial shared hosting solutions these days, the only real difference from a dedicated server or VPS is that you have less CPU time and don't have full access on the server to install new software or customize existing software.

Comment: I don't think this really is the responsibility of web hosts... if you create directories writable by all, you'll expect them to be writable by other users won't you? What is hard to believe is that Symfony creates folders writable by all...

Comment: Well, they actually give you a good reason for this--because most web servers are configured to run a PHP script as `nobody`, so if they didn't, then they'd have no access to the cache files. So on the one hand, you shouldn't be in the habit of creating publicly writable files/directories, but on the other, you want your PHP scripts to run with the least privileges possible to minimize the damage caused by a malicious script. And given that most shared hosts don't trust their users not to execute malicious scripts or to use proper file permissions, the use of chroot jails makes sense.

Comment: The page you have suggested had come to my notice but it only  complicates my perception.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays in shared hosting u get a directory above public_html. for eg:

```
/home/mysite.com
   -logs
   -etc
    ....
   -public_html
```

So the things you want to publicly accessible can go in public_html and the things you dont want can reside outside public_html.

In symfony2, the web folder contains the front controllers (app.php, app_dev.php) and the resources like images,css, js files. just rename the web folder to public_html. read this article on how to rename web folder to public_html: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory